# Selecting training images for object verification(siamese network), different number of examples per object

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, conv-neural-network, unbalanced-classes, overfitting

I'm trying to build a model for object verification (my first not tutorial-guided project of this kind). I saw an approach using a siamese network in the coursera deep learning course by Andrew Ng. The method used there (for face verification) is to train a CNN to extract a feature vector from images. The difference between the vectors calculated for two images is then used to determine whether they show the same object/person or not.

I am about to start a project where I would like to use this approach and I got a data set that seems to be well fit to the purpose but before starting, I'd be grateful for some advice from experienced ML-engineers/DS on how to best build my training/validation/test sets from the dataset I have.

The question I'm most uncertain about is how many images I should choose from those available for each object in the dataset. The number varies vastly! Here's an overview, sorted by the number of available pictures per object:

- 2-4 imgs: 100 objects
- 5-10 imgs: 200 objects
- 11-20 imgs: 200 objects
- 21-30 imgs: 150 objects
- 31-40 imgs: 100 objects
- 41-50 imgs: 70 objects
- 51-60 imgs: 60 objects
- 61-70 imgs: 50 objects
- 71-80 imgs: 30 objects
- 81-90 imgs: 80 objects
- 91-100 imgs: 20 objects
- 101-130 imgs: 40 objects
- 131-200 imgs: 60 objects
- 201-300 imgs: 40 objects
- 301-400 imgs: 20 objects
- 201-300 imgs: 40 objects
- 201-300 imgs: 40 objects
- 401+ imgs: 25 objects

Total: ~ 77.000 images for 1200 objects

Here are my thoughts so far:

- **if I just used all images** (e.g. 5 for one object, 400 for another) that would lead to my model doing much better for objects similar to those with a large number of training pictures. So it would overfit to those and generalize badly to unseen data with different properties.
- **Min./max. 20 - 50:** I could select objects with a minimum of 20 pictures only, and from all with more than that select a maximum of 50 pictures. What I don't like about this idea is that the number of different objects is reduced by quite some number. I would end up with about 30.000 images for 700 objects, ignoring/wasting 500 objects in the dataset. That's also a large number of images for just 700 objects and I somehow feel that this might lead to overfitting and bad generalization as well.
- **Min./max. 5 - 10:** perhaps I should change the limits: min. 5, max. 10 pictures per object. That would give me about 18446 pictures for 1105 objects, with a maximum difference of just 5 pictures between the objects. That should do a better job in terms of avoiding overfitting, right?

The latter approach would also allow for much larger validation and test sets, which I guess would be good as well. Most of the objects in the dataset would be used, too.

I hope it's clear from this description what causes my uncertainty about how to choose from the data. My intuition is that I somehow have too balance between

1. overfitting to those objects with a large amount of images
2. overfitting in general and
3. wasting the chance to use all the objects in my dataset

Are these (beginner's) thoughts completely false or am I at least on the right track in some ways?

Thanks in advance for any of your insights, experiences and advice!

Best regards,
Chris